# Bash redirect not appearing unless using append?

Tags: bash, redirect

Why does the following work when using `>>` but not with `>`?

[image]

GNU bash, version 4.4.12

Comment: For text content, please use actual text (in code format) in your question rather than images.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're seeing this happen is because the shell will start by setting up the redirection, and when you use `>`, it will clear the file that you're redirecting to. So in this case, the first thing that happens is the `test` file gets cleared. Then, it runs the commands. So now that `test` is an empty file, `cat test` will be empty as well and so `tr` will receive an empty input from the pipe, and thus nothing will be redirected to the file.

Comment: and how to solve the problems,without using the second file

Comment: Based on the way Bash works it's not possible to do without using a temporary file. Bash always starts the redirect before running the command.

Comment: See [BashPitfall #13](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cat_file_.7C_sed_s.2Ffoo.2Fbar.2F_.3E_file).